# Telegram retrieving groupname by user id

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using telethon `GetFullUserRequest` to retrieve `user id` and `name`.
I want to see if this user id is a member of a group, or even a member of multiple groups.
I googled but I can't find a solution.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe there is no such possibility, that would be a personal information violation. However, there is a function to get a list of groups you have in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @go2nirvana [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171483/telegram-retrieving-groupname-by-user-id#comment113476388_64171483), you can get the common chats, but that's all you can do (there is simply no way to know which broadcast channels they're in, or what groups unless you're in them too).

This is done with [`GetCommonChatsRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_common_chats.html) and is what clients show as "groups in common" when you open someone's profile:

```py
async def main():
    result = await client(functions.messages.GetCommonChatsRequest(
        user_id='username',
        max_id=0,
        limit=100
    ))

    for chat in result.chats:
        ...
```